# How to update the value of a single property within a state object in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

So I have the following object structure:

```
const SamplePalette = {
  id: 1,
  name: "Sample Palette",
  description: "this is a short description",
  swatches: [
    { 
      val: "#FF6245",
      tints: ["#FFE0DB", "#FFA797"],
      shades: ["#751408", "#C33F27"]
    },
    {
      val: "#FFFDA4",
      tints: ["#FFFFE1"],
      shades: ["#CCCB83"]
    },
    {
      val: "#BFE8A3",
      tints: ["#E7FFD7"],
      shades: ["#95B77E"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Let's imagine that this object is managed by the state of my app like this:

```
this.state = {
  currentPalette: SamplePalette,
}
```

My question is how would I go about updating the `val` property of a given swatch object in the `swatches` array? Or more generally - how do I only update pieces of this object?

I tried using the `update` helper as well as to figure out how `Object.assign()` works, however I've been unsuccessful and frankly can't really grasp the syntax by just looking at examples.

Also, since I'm going to be modifying this object quite a lot, should I look into maybe using Redux?

**[EDIT]**

I tried @maxim.sh suggestion but with no success:

```
this.setState(
     { currentPalette: {...this.state.currentPalette, 
         swatches[0].val: newValue}
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider you have new `new_swatches`

I think the clearer way is to get array, update it and put back as:

```
let new_swatches = this.state.currentPalette.swatches;
new_swatches[0].val = newValue; 
this.setState(
         { currentPalette: 
             { ...this.state.currentPalette, swatches: new_swatches } 
 });
```

---

Also you have : [Immutability Helpers](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html) or https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper

Available Commands

```
{$push: array} push() all the items in array on the target.
{$unshift: array} unshift() all the items in array on the target.
{$splice: array of arrays} for each item in arrays call splice() on the target with the parameters provided by the item.
{$set: any} replace the target entirely.
{$merge: object} merge the keys of object with the target.
{$apply: function} passes in the current value to the function and updates it with the new returned value.
```

---

Comment: Hey! Thanks for pitching in! And what about updating a more deeply nested property. For example the `val` property of a an object contained within the swatches array. I tried something like this but of course it didn't work... `this.setState({ currentPalette: {...this.state.currentPalette, swatches[0].val: newValue}})`